# What is the relation between font size in tkinter and window size/ pixel density factor/ original screen resolution in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, window

This question has stumped me and I can't seem to figure out why its not scaling properly per device.

I have run my code on 3 different computers (2 laptops and one android tablet) and I don't get what is happening.

I am also using a scaling factor (dpi/72). What is shown is the original scaling factor, but I make the scaling factor proportional to my main laptops scaling factor with this code:

```
dpi = root.winfo_fpixels('1i')
factor = dpi / 72
factor_multiplier = (.40*factor) +.46
factor = factor/factor_multiplier
starting_frame.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', factor)
```

---

main computer:

screen size : 1920x1980 , window size : 1280x960, scaling factor: 1.3, font that is correct : 40

others:

screen size : 1366x768, window size : 1912x683, scaling factor: 1.3, font that is correct : 30

screen size : 2560x1600 , window size : 1750x1311, scaling factor: 5.7, font that is correct : 30

Each window size is roughly 88% of the actual screen res, and converted into 4:3 roughly.

I don't understand how my other two laptops can have such different screen resolutions + dpi but still need the same font size. also the dpi is proportional to my main laptops so that might be a factor as well.All the fonts "fit" the window, they don't all fit a box that has been proportionally made (i.e the box is proportionally the same for all screen resolutions as shown in full relevant code bellow).

relevant code is this:

```
def font_size_calc(): #this is the problematic code that isnt scaling the font size right
    global r2_width, r2_height
    x = r2_width*int(r2_height)
    return str(math.ceil((-(1/106545)*x) + 51.533155004927)) #linear equation I made, slope = fontsize/screen's area
    '''
    I tried creating a linear equation based on the fonts that worked for
    2 of my devices, but a device with a smaller screen resolution than both of my devices needs a font size of 30 like my highest res device
    to have the words stay in the box
    '''
starting_frame.create_text(adjusted_pixels(2,"x"),adjusted_pixels(2.742857,"y"),
    text = "Enter number of laps",fill = "gray", font=("Calibri "+ font_size_calc())) #calls font_size_calc() to get a working font size
    #I want the text to fit in the box created by the var border, it works on my laptop and tablet, but not another old laptop with a smaller screen res
    #obviously my equation is wrong but im not sure how to scale the font to work in all cases
```

code for the program (edited so that you can run it too):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import math
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = tk.Tk()
dpi = root.winfo_fpixels('1i')
factor = dpi / 72 #gets how many times biger the dpi is than the standard 72, used for making the screen widgets proportional later
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()


ratio_1 = width * height
ratio_2 = 1 #init
r2_width = 4 #setting the window to a 4/3 resolution
r2_height = 3

while (ratio_1 / ratio_2) != 1.6875: #making sure that the new window is 88% the area of the old window
    r2_height = r2_width / 1.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 #gets hieght
    ratio_2 = r2_width * r2_height # gets the area of the new screen size
    r2_width = r2_width + 1 #increases the width by one

    if (ratio_1/ratio_2) <= 1.6875: #makes sure it doesnt go too far over
        break
    if width + 1 == r2_width: #another check to make sure it doesnt keep going
        break

print("{} x {} = {}".format(str(r2_width),str(r2_height),str(ratio_1/ratio_2)))#prints your ending resolution to manually check accuracy

root.geometry(str(r2_width) + "x"+ str(int(r2_height))) #sets window resolution
starting_frame = tk.Canvas(root) #makes a frame

factor_multiplier = (.40*factor) +.46 #makes a multiplier based on an equation I cam up with (im so glad it was linear)
factor = factor/factor_multiplier #sets factor to be this new peoportion
starting_frame.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', factor)#adjusts tkinter scaling factor for the pixels
starting_frame.place(height=int(r2_height), width = r2_width) #places the frame




images = []
def create_rectangle(frame, x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs): #this works so dont worry about this function
    if 'alpha' in kwargs:
        alpha = int(kwargs.pop('alpha') * 255)
        fill = kwargs.pop('fill')
        fill = root.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)
        image = Image.new('RGBA', (x2-x1, y2-y1), fill)
        images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
        frame.create_image(x1, y1, image=images[-1], anchor='nw')
    return frame.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)

def adjusted_pixels(number, x_or_y): #this code creates new coordinates based on set numbers I ahve already made and works aswell
    global r2_width, r2_height

    if x_or_y == 'x':
        print(int(r2_width / number))
        return(int(r2_width / number))
    else:
        print(int(r2_height / number))
        return(int(r2_height / number))

def font_size_calc(): #this is the problematic code that isnt scaling the font size right
    global r2_width, r2_height
    x = r2_width*int(r2_height)
    return str(math.ceil((-(1/106545)*x) + 51.533155004927)) #linear equation I made, slope = fontsize/screen's area
    '''
    I tried creating a linear equation based on the fonts that worked for
    2 of my devices, but a device with a smaller screen resolution than both of my devices needs a font size of 30 like my highest res device
    to have the words stay in the box
    '''


boarder = create_rectangle(starting_frame,adjusted_pixels(3.368421,"x"), adjusted_pixels(3.2,'y'),
    adjusted_pixels(1.4222222,"x"), adjusted_pixels(1.45454545,"y"), fill='black',alpha = .78,outline = "red") #creates a box thats slightly transparent, works fine
lap_text = starting_frame.create_text(adjusted_pixels(2,"x"),adjusted_pixels(2.742857,"y"),
    text = "Enter number of laps",fill = "gray", font=("Calibri "+ font_size_calc())) #calls font_size_calc() to get a working font size
    #I want the text to fit in the box created by the var border, it works on my laptop and tablet, but not another old laptop with a smaller screen res
    #obviously my equation is wrong but im not sure how to scale the font to work in all cases

root.mainloop()
```

You might be wondering why I am messing with the scaling factor (dpi/72) instead of just making it 1. I happen to like the way my program looked on my laptop and I wanted it to be proportionally the same across every device, that's why I mess with it.

Again though, I cant seem to get the font size to scale at all based on resolution, I'm not sure why a screen with a lower res (same dpi as main laptop) and screen with a higher res (different dpi than my main laptop) both require the same font size but my main laptop requires a different one.

Comment: Are you aware that `dpi = root.winfo_fpixels('1i')` uses the scaling factor to determine the dpi, and that the scaling factor may not accurately set for your system? In other words, I don't think your `dpi` calculation is guaranteed to be correct. If the `dpi` value is wrong, all of your other calculations will be wrong.

Comment: @BryanOakley isnt the variable `factor` just finding what scaling factor `dpi = root.winfo_fpixels('1i')` is using? So it shouldn't matter right?

Comment: Nvm I see what you mean, I ran the calculation manually and it is wrong (I did that before and I thought it was correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was this: I was calculating the font based on the screen window, not the full screen size. This is I was getting incorrect sizing.